# Bending angle equation of particle in a magnetic and electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

Using the equations for an Electric field and Magnetic field between two plates:
$$ 
E = \frac Vr
$$
$$
B=\frac{2I}{2\pi r}\cdot\mu_0
$$
where $V$ is plate voltage, $r$ is plate separation, $I$ is plate current, and $\mu_0$ permeability of free space, I want to write equations for the bending angle experienced by a charged particle. I've been checking these equations using Python Pint.

The equation for the electric field bending angle works just fine:
$$
\theta_E = \frac qc \cdot \frac{E\cdot L}{p\cdot \beta}$$
where $q$ is charge, $c$ is speed of light, $L$ is plate/electrode length, $p$ is particle momentum, and $\beta$ is Lorentz beta. In Pint, it's happily unitless:

```
V = SI("1kV")
r = 70 * SI("mm")
L = SI("1m")
p = SI("1 GeV/c")
beta = 0.7
# Eq 1
E = V/r
E.to("V/m") # 14285.714285714284 volt/meter
# Eq 3
q = SI("1 e")
c = SI("c")
theta_E = (q/c) * ((E*L)/(p*beta))
theta_E.to("rad") # 2.0408163265306126×10-5 radian
```

The equation for magnetic field bending angle, however, doesn't seem to match up:
$$
\theta_B = \frac{B\cdot q\cdot L}p
$$

```
# Eq 2
I = SI("1A")
H = ((2*I)/(2*np.pi*r))
B = H*mu0
B.to("A/m") # 5.714285717396433×10-6 ampere/meter
# Eq 4
theta_B = (B*q*L)/(p)
theta_B.to("rad") # DimensionalityError
```

I've checked these by hand, and I get unitless for equation 3, and `[time] ** 2 / [length] / [mass]` for equation 4.

Is the equation wrong, or my pint/dimensional analysis misguided?

I've been using [Wiedemann](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-18317-6) (equation 4.33) and [an old CERN booklet](https://cds.cern.ch/record/104153) (section 3) as sources. Are there better references?

Comment: How does a plate run a current? How is your  circuit build? What direction is B

Comment: I'm only interested in the angle in the direction of B. The current is run between the plates; I'm not sure how else to describe the circuit.